# Set of most linearly independent vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a matrix $M^{m*n}$ where $n>m$ I would like to chose $m$ column from $M$ which are the most linearly independent set of columns in $M$. I have seen that it might be possible wit SVD by sorting the sigmas. If it is can somebody explain way or give me another way to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "most linearly independent set"? I guess you can use the determinant of the chosen minor as a measure of how linearly independent the minor matrix is. However, there may be other measures for that (such as normalized determinants, or some other way using singular values etc). So the question as is is a bit vague. You could perhaps provide some context, or maybe make your question more precise.

Comment: HI. you are right determinant might be a way to measure how linearly independent the set is. However in my case n = 10000 and m = 100 so it would be a bit time consuming to try all possible minor set. I am looking for faster solution. by "most linearly independent set" I mean suppose we have P which contains all the possible subset of size 128 find the one which has some minimal linearly independence measure (like singular value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the maximal linearly independent set from a given set of $n$ vectors (columns of $M$). Since $M$ is $m\times n$ and $n>m$, any linearly independent subset of the columns can't have members more than $m$. Thus, your problem boils down to finding the largest column subset. This is a very important problem of active research in many applied areas like signal/image processing and machine learning. Traditional approaches would be to do Gaussian elimination or even Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization. However, for large dimensional matrices, this doesn't scale well. Do look upon column subset selection, you will come across large amount of applied research on this topic.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the field. I will need to do some reading on column subset selection. Thanks